# Mouse in games - Alternative input methods

Tags: mouse, diablo-iii

My shoulder hurts if I use the mouse for more than 30 minutes at a time, that's why I currently only play games with an xbox 360 gamepad.

However, with Diablo 3 I will not be able to do that.

Does anyone know of an alternate input method that has similar precision to a mouse? I've been thinking about using a Wiimote, but I don't think its accurate enough. Maybe a PS Move?

Comment: Check this http://www.mflohc.mb.ca/fact_sheets_folder/mouse_related_pain.html

Comment: If your shoulder starts hurting from using a mouse, you have some ergonomics issues to work out.  Properly supporting your wrist and lower arm will do you more good in the long run.

Comment: you should not be moving your shoulders that much while using a mouse

Comment: In fact you do not need to move your shoulder at all, just try to use higher cursor speed and do not move your higher (or even lower) arm at all.

Answer (score 4):

You might still consider mice, as there are Trackball mice which are similar to normal mouse precision but operate in a different way:

[image]

This for example is the "Logitech M570 Trackball". Basically instead of moving the mouse on your table you move the Trackball with your thumb. Your shoulder does not move a bit.

There was once a top professional Counter Strike player that used a similar mouse, but I forgot his name, which proves that you can make it work even in precision games that require fast reflexes. Here is an old discussion about this topic: [Gamespot Thread](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/26208585)

This does not really concern your question, but I guess you are using your mouse in a wrong way. Day[9], a professional Starcraft veteran has a 1 hour show that explains how to correctly use your mouse and keyboard for Starcraft 2. You can easily adapt this to Diablo 3 or any computer game. Check it out: [Day9 Daily 252](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUohpQKVf_A).

Answer (score 3):

There are a million options, but I consider most novelties. As others point out, ergonomics are probably the core of your issue. Since thumbs seem to work better for you then wrist movements, one option to consider is a trackball mouse like the Logitech 570 I've linked below. There is a definite learning curve for using them, and I think they'll never be "FPS" precision or speed, but I've played with folks that converted and used them effectively in games like Starcraft and Diablo.

http://www.officedepot.com/mb/skupage.do?skuid=989412

Comment: I use that exact trackball and would have to disagree with the idea that they will never be FPS precise.  I have the sensitivity on mine set such that one full roll from left to right on the ball is a 180 degree turn.  It allows for very quick reactions, and with a bit of practice, precision is at least as good as a mouse.  I tend to snipe, and don't have any problems with it.

Comment: My hats off to you, no insult intended. My overall FPS skillz on PC are less than best in class anyway - so unlike the OP I mostly stick to what I know rather than trying new things.  Maybe I'd feel differently if it caused chronic pain.